# Float parameters instead of int for new Rectangle() c#?

Tags: c#, geometry, drawellipse

Is it possible to use as parameters float instead of int for the Rectangle class in c#?! Or any way in which I can do this by creating maybe a new class similar to Rectangle that takes as parameters float?

I am trying to use this within the `e.Graphics.DrawEllipse`.

Example :

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Black, stroke), new Rectangle(10,20,30,40);
```

Instead of 10,20,30,40 I would like to use floats.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the `RectangleF` class in `System.Drawing` which takes `single-precision` `floating point` numbers as parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/kwafa1d7(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx